# JCarousel: Sort images

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm using [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) plugin to display dinamically added images:

```
var car = $("#image-carousel").data('jcarousel');
car.add(0, html);
```

First parameter of *add* method asks for a position. I've tried to give incremental positions in order to select the exact sequence of images, but *add()* adds the image without any order.

The question is, how may I add secuential images to jcarousel? Or alternativelly, it's possible to sort images programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I haven't found any solution using JCarousel. Instead I've sorted the inner LI items:

```
function _sortCarousel(a,b) {
    return $(a).find("input").val() > $(b).find("input").val() ? 1 : -1;
}


$("#image-carousel li").sort(_sortCarousel).appendTo("#image-carousel");
```

Of course, code inside *_sortCarousel* should be changed to reflect the sorting rules you need.